# How can I identify the coroutines responses in fetchTickers CCXT when using async?

Tags: python, ccxt

I have such a question, not how I can't come up with a solution.
I want to asynchronously call the [fetchTickers](https://docs.ccxt.com/#/README?id=price-tickers) function from the [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) library for two exchanges. My code works, but I can't identify which exchange responded. The response is constantly being overwritten.

I would like to get such a structure

```
{'binance': {'data 1'}, 'bybit': {'data 1'}}
```

however asyncio.gather returns an array and I can't figure out where what data is.

Any ideas on how to identify this data?

My Example:

```
import asyncio
import os
import sys


root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(root + '/python')

import ccxt.async_support as ccxt


async def test():
    instance = []
    for exchange_id in ['binance', 'bybit']:
        exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
        instance.append(exchange_class())

    tickers = []
    for exchange in instance:
        tickers += [exchange.fetchTickers()]
    response = await asyncio.gather(*tickers)
    print(response)


asyncio.run(test())
```

I was thinking of trying to use this somehow, but I couldn't figure out how to use it

```
tickers += [asyncio.create_task(exchange.fetchTickers(), name=exchange.id)]
```

Comment: Please have a look at it
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

it says -> 
If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task.

If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an aggregate list of returned values. The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in was.
if the response is a list of results that list represents the index of exchange_ids
you can map it accordingly

you can also use asyncio.TaskGroup to do the same thing

Comment: Thank you - really, how could I so inattentively read and skip this item